# QUERY data only when email is not in another sheet - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need help trying to query a data sheet only when an email IS NOT in another sheet.

Play here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10RMPMgLPmfcKl4iazSQiT-HerpQkUggM3fYBunugPUI/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come with not complex one

```
=QUERY(DATA!A1:C,"Select * where A <>'"&TEXTJOIN("' and A <>'",true,'Spam List'!A1:A)&"'")
```

`<>` to use as `not equal to`

`TEXTJOIN("' and A <>'"...)` to just repeat the QUERY code

by the way I created in "Failed test" sheet, Column I