# QUERY data only when value EXISTS in another sheet - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I created a similar request 2 years ago: [QUERY data only when email is not in another sheet - Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61403286/query-data-only-when-email-is-not-in-another-sheet-google-sheets)

But I'm now **trying to do the opposite**, by only querying data when it DOES exist in the other sheet.

Changing the operator to = seems to show nothings, when I thought it might be the opposite to <>

**Shows everything that's not in "ONLY SHOW THESE IN QUERY"**

WHERE A <>'"&TEXTJOIN("' AND A <>'",true,'ONLY SHOW THESE IN QUERY'!A1:A)...

**Shows nothing**

WHERE A ='"&TEXTJOIN("' AND A ='",true,'ONLY SHOW THESE IN QUERY'!A1:A)..

Here's the editable sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H39uZNfQ_VyK-YUvFY1vdeAnVcd9Y_PLS2MdAxZTh9c/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with your current approach, you'll need to change your `AND` in the `TEXTJOIN` to `OR`, since no single entry in the first list will match *all* of the entries in your second list.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I did try this but maybe I modified something else..

Comment: Given your spreadsheet and minimal example, this worked for me as expected. If it is not working in your real-world spreadsheet, feel free to make a copy of that spreadsheet, truncate and sanitize the data as you see fit, and share a link to that copy.